# No matching client found for package name with Flavors

Tags: android, android-productflavors

Im using flavor for generated several versions of the same app, where the only thing that change is the style, but i need upload severals apk's to the playstore, but i have a problem when try build the project, mark "No matching client found for package name" error.

My build.gradle file is:

```
starwing {
        applicationId "mx.com.locker.starwing"
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.11"
    }
    puntoarq {
        applicationId "mx.com.locker.starwing.puntoarq"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
```

The "mx.com.locker.starwing.puntoarq" is the one not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `applicationIdSuffix` for changing the application id of each product flavor like:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mx.com.locker"
        ...
    }
    productFlavors {
        starwing {
            applicationIdSuffix ".starwing"
            versionCode 11
            versionName "1.11"
        }
        puntoarq {
            applicationIdSuffix ".puntoarq"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1"
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure you have your res folder for each flavor in their respective directory like this:

```
# common/default resources here
app/src/main/res/values
                       \___ /styles.xml
                       |___ /colors.xml
                        \__ ...

# starwing resources here
app/src/starwing/res/values
                       \___ /styles.xml
                       |___ /colors.xml
                        \__ ...

# puntoarq resources here
app/src/puntoarq/res/values
                       \___ /styles.xml
                       |___ /colors.xml
                        \__ ...
```

The same for source code files and of course with the `google-services.json` if you are using some google service.

```
# common/default resources here
app/src/main/google-services.json

# starwing resources here
app/src/starwing/google-services.json

# puntoarq resources here
app/src/puntoarq/google-services.json
```

You can build your specific flavor choosing the build variant from Android Studio or running `./gradlew assembleStarwingRelease` or `./gradlew assemblePuntoarqRelease`.

You could take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) for more information.